# How to get wxPython video player working in windows

Tags: python, video, wxpython

I'm trying to get the wxPython video player described [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216704) to work in Windows, so that I can do some minor modifications to it and get a script running that will let a user hit the spacebar while watching a video and spit out a record of the timing of each spacebar press.  So far, though, I can't even get the videoplayer working; when I try to open a video, I get the following error message:

```
Unable to load (filename): Unsupported format?
```

A little google searching turned up the possibility that I might be missing gstreamer packages, so I installed the closest thing I could find from [here](http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/downloads/list), but it still doesn't work.  What exactly do I need to have installed to get wxPython to play videos, and how do I install it?

Thanks!

Comment: please indicate which formats are you trying to reproduce that generate the error. And post the real traceback you get.

Comment: Not an answer, but just FYI, wxPython is fairly outdated from what I understand. Not sure of your project specs, but you may consider researching pyGTK and GStreamer (the video component for PyGTK). It should do largely the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxPython should use GStreamer on Linux, if available. See http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wxpython-gstreamer-and-overlapping-panel-staticText-td4834139.html or http://pythonide.blogspot.com/2008/03/howto-write-wxpython-video-player-with.html although I don't see why that matters when the OP was talking about Windows.

I created a simple media player using the mplayer control. You can read about it here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/ It was tested on Windows XP and Windows 7 with no issues.